# Does Android Keeps History of Changes in Views?

Tags: java, android

Does Android Keeps History of Change in (View or Activity) same as any Log file! and Can we use that information occurring to our requirement? I want to set Some flags on the base of that information for future purpose in application!

Comment: What have you tried? what have you investigated? what are you actually asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad. There can be different kind of history: history of touches, history of text editing, history of view location, history of started activities, history of started applications etc. But Android only keeps what is important for Android users. For instance, it keeps list of recently launched applications, or activities in a task stack. But this is not really a history. There is also no history of view changes or so.

Answering your question - no. Most likely you won't find anything, what you can reliable use as a history. If you need the real history, you need to set corresponding listeners and implement it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes, By default Android keeps the History for the Activity if the Flag is not set. You can set this Flag through Intent by this code.

`Intent i = new Intent();                              i.setFlags(|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY );`

**Flag Description** 
If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also be set with the noHistory attribute.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) link for further information about the FLAG used in android Intent.
Hope this helps.